# How to get portfolio stock share positions by day via SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I need to calculate my stock portfolio position by day. In my postgres (v10) database i have:

PORTFOLIOS TABLE

```
+----------------------+-------------------------------+
|     id(INTEGER)      |      portfolio_name(CHAR)     |
+----------------------+-------------------------------+
|     portfolio_1      |        my portfolio           |
+----------------------+-------------------------------+
```

TRANSACTIONS TABLE

```
+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| id(INTEGER) | portfolio_id(INTEGER) | stock_id(INTEGER) | price(FLOAT) | share(FLOAT) | transaction_date(TIMESTAMP) | transaction_type(CHAR) |
+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
|           1 | portfolio_1           | stock_1           |        12,34 |         3000 | 2019-06-03 15:36:29 +0000   | BUY_SELL               |
|           2 | portfolio_1           | stock_2           |        30,34 |         2000 | 2019-06-03 15:36:29 +0000   | BUY_SELL               |
|           3 | portfolio_1           | stock_1           |        35,34 |        -1000 | 2019-06-13 12:06:29 +0000   | BUY_SELL               |
+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
```

STOCK VALUES TABLE

```
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| id(INTEGER) | stock_id(INTEGER) |   value_date(TIMESTAMP)   | open_value(FLOAT) | close_value(FLOAT) | high_value(FLOAT) | low_value(FLOAT) |
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|           1 | stock_1           | 2019-01-01 10:33:16 +0000 |              30.6 |               30.6 |              30.6 |             30.6 |
|           2 | stock_1           | 2019-01-02 10:33:16 +0000 |              30.6 |               30.6 |              30.6 |             30.6 |
|           3 | stock_1           | 2019-01-03 10:33:16 +0000 |              30.6 |               30.6 |              30.6 |             30.6 |
|           4 | stock_1           | 2019-01-04 10:33:16 +0000 |              30.6 |               30.6 |              30.6 |             30.6 |
|           5 | stock_1           | 2019-01-05 10:33:16 +0000 |              30.6 |               30.6 |              30.6 |             30.6 |
|           6 | stock_1           | 2019-01-06 10:33:16 +0000 |              30.6 |               30.6 |              30.6 |             30.6 |
|        .... |                   |                           |                   |                    |                   |                  |
|          17 | stock_2           | 2019-01-05 10:33:16 +0000 |              10.4 |               10.4 |              10.4 |             10.4 |
|          18 | stock_2           | 2019-01-06 10:33:16 +0000 |              10.4 |               10.4 |              10.4 |             10.4 |
|        .... |                   |                           |                   |                    |                   |                  |
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

I would like to generate this result with an SQL query:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| portfolio_id(INTEGER) |   stock_id(INTEGER)   | date(TIMESTAMP) |   share(FLOAT)   |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| portfolio_1           | stock_1               | 2019-06-03      | 3000             |
| portfolio_1           | stock_2               | 2019-06-03      | 2000             |
| portfolio_1           | stock_1               | 2019-06-04      | 3000             |
| portfolio_1           | stock_2               | 2019-06-04      | 2000             |
| portfolio_1           | stock_1               | 2019-06-05      | 3000             |
| portfolio_1           | stock_2               | 2019-06-06      | 2000             |
| ...                   |                       |                 |                  |
| portfolio_1           | stock_1               | 2019-06-13      | 2000 (3000-1000) |
| ....                  |                       |                 |                  |
| portfolio_1           | stock_1               | now             | 2000             |
| portfolio_1           | stock_2               | now             | 2000             |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

After playing with subquery, i haven't been able to do it with SQL. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!

EDIT: you can find an db-fiddle here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oSZ4SbvK5uFWSzmdTH5eAy/1

Comment: . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle?

Comment: sure here it is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oSZ4SbvK5uFWSzmdTH5eAy/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by generating the dates using `generate_series()`:

```
select p.portfolio_id, p.stock_id, p.dte, 
       Sum(t.share) over (partition by p.portfolio_id, p.stock_id order by p.dte) as shares
from (select t.portfolio_id, s.stock_id, generate_series(t.min_td, current_date, interval '1 day') as dte
      from (select portfolio_id, min(transaction_date)::date as min_td
            from transactions t 
            group by portfolio_id
           ) t cross join
           (select distinct stock_id from transactions) s
     ) p left join
     transactions t
     on t.portfolio_id = p.portfolio_id and t.stock_id = p.stock_id and t.transaction_date::date = p.dte
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e1c511468dba2b3f054001b3f5bf6759) is a db<>fiddle.